# Create Flowable from while loop

Tags: java, android, rx-java2, repository-pattern

I am pretty new to RxJava and I need to create repository with several datasources. It is complex to me because there are several smaller subtasks which I don't know how to implement with RxJava.

First I have self written dao, which process InputStream, and provides Items in the specified range. Currently it simply collects data in a list, but I want to provide Items one by one using flowable; Currently it privides `Maybe<List<Item>>`. Also there several errors need to be transmitted to higher level (datasource). Such as EndOfFile, to notify DataSource that data fully cached;

`Dao.class`:

```
List<Item> loadRange(int start, int number) throws ... {
    ...
    while(...) {
        ...
        //TODO contribute item to flowable
        resultList.add(new Item(...)) 

    }
    return resultList;
}
```

`Maybe<List<Item>>` method just created `Maybe.fromCallable()`;

Please help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work for this :

```
Flowable<Item> loadRange(int start, int number) {
        return Flowable.create(emitter -> {
            try {
                while (...){
                    emitter.onNext(new Item());
                }
                emitter.onComplete();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                emitter.onError(e);
            }
        }, BackpressureStrategy.BUFFER);
    }
```

I assume once the loop is done you want to complete, also send errors downstream, rather than handle on the method signature.  Also you can change the `BackPressureStrategy` to suit your usecase i.e `DROP`, `LATEST` etc..

As you're new to RxJava, the anonymous class would be :

```
Flowable<Item> loadRange(int start, int number) {
        return Flowable.create(new FlowableOnSubscribe<Item>() {
            @Override public void subscribe(FlowableEmitter<Item> emitter) {
                try {
                    while (...){
                        emitter.onNext(new Item());
                    }
                    emitter.onComplete();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    emitter.onError(e);
                }
            }
        }, BackpressureStrategy.BUFFER);
    }
```